# Flask Form with parameters

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to define a Flask form with one parameter. This was my approach:

`forms.py`

```
class RegisterPatternForm(FlaskForm):
    cursorPatients = MongoClient('localhost:27017').myDb["coll"].find({"field1": self.myParam}).sort([("id", 1)])
    patientOpts = []
    for pt in cursorPatients:
        row = (str(pt.get("id")), "{} {}, {}".format(pt.get("surname1"), pt.get("surname2"), pt.get("name")))
        patientOpts.append(row)

    patients = SelectMultipleField('Select the patient', validators=[Optional()], choices=patientOpts)
    submit = SubmitField('Register')

    def __init__(self, myParam, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterPatternForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.myParam = myParam
```

`routes.py`

```
myParam = 5
form = RegisterPatternForm(myParam)
```

Basically, I want to read the variable `myParam` defined on `routes.py` on the form `RegisterPatternForm`. The insertion of the param in `routes.py` works, as well as the `__init__` method in `RegisterPatternForm`. Where it fails is when reading the field on the line that starts with `cursorPatients`.

Therefore, my question is, how can I solve this problem in order to be able to read `myParam` value inside the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*About problem.*

`cursorPatients` / `patients` / etc is a class-level variable(`static` variable). It means you do not have `instance` and `properties` at this level. Roughly speaking, You trying to use `self` to access to an object but object was not created.

If I understood correctly you need to change some `choices` using a `Form property`.

Let's trying to change choices using `__init__`:

```
class RegisterPatternForm(FlaskForm):
    patients = SelectMultipleField('Select the patient',
                                   validators=[Optional()],
                                   choices=[('one', 'one')])

    def __init__(self, patients_choices: list = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if patients_choices:
            self.patients.choices = patients_choices

RegisterPatternForm()  # default choices - [('one', 'one')]
RegisterPatternForm(patients_choices=[('two', 'two')])  # new choices
```

As you can see `patients` choices are changing using `constructor`. So in your case it should be something like this:

```
class RegisterPatternForm(FlaskForm):
    patients = SelectMultipleField('Select the patient',
                                   validators=[Optional()],
                                   choices=[])

    def __init__(self, myParam: int, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.myParam = myParam
        self.patients.choices = self._mongo_mock()

    def _mongo_mock(self) -> list:
        """
        db = MongoClient('localhost:27017').myDb["coll"]
        result = []
        for pt in db.find({"field1": self.myParam}).sort([("id", 1)]):
            blablabla....
        return result
        Just an example(I `mocked` mongo)
        """
        return [(str(i), str(i)) for i in range(self.myParam)]


form1 = RegisterPatternForm(1)
form2 = RegisterPatternForm(5)
print(form1.patients.choices)  # [('0', '0')]
print(form2.patients.choices)  # [('0', '0'), ('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('4', '4')]
```

Hope this helps.