# Flask WTForms FieldList based on input parameter not working

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm trying to instantiate a Flask Form that contains a FieldList, for which I want to change the FormField based on an additional input parameter. Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59554877/flask-form-with-parameters), my setup looks like this:

```
class Child1(FlaskForm):
    class Meta:
        csrf = False
    
    field = SelectField()

class Child2(FlaskForm):
    class Meta:
        csrf = False
    
    field = StringField()

class Parent(FlaskForm):
    field_list_form = FieldList(FormField(Child1))
    def __init__(self, select_child="child1", *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if select_child == "child2":
            self.field_list_form = FieldList(FormField(Child2))
```

Now in my Flask app, when I use the default parameter, doing this works fine

```
form = Parent()
for idx in range(42):
    form.field_list_form.append_entry({})
```

But when doing

```
form = Parent(select_child="child2")
for idx in range(42):
    form.field_list_form.append_entry({})
```

I get
`AttributeError: 'UnboundField' object has no attribute 'append_entry'`

How should I do this differently?

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to already have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43268323).

However, another solution is to wrap the class declaration with a function taking `select_child` as an argument and, depending on the argument value, create the FormField with either of your Child classes.

In your case, it would be:

```
def create_parent(select_child="child1"):
    class Parent(FlaskForm):
        if select_child == 'child1':
            field_list_form = FieldList(FormField(Child1))
        elif select_child == "child2":
                field_list_form = FieldList(FormField(Child2))
                
    return Parent()
```

Then `form = Parent(select_child="child2")` becomes `form = create_parent(select_child="child2")`

Further details [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38206179/11113374).